# unexpected error cloning typescript git repository

Tags: git, codeplex

using both sourcetree and commandline I receive this error:

D:\GitHub\typescript>git clone  https://git01.codeplex.com/typescript

Cloning into 'typescript'...

remote: Counting objects: 454417, done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (39295/39295), done.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly7.99 MiB | 459.00 KiB/s

fatal: early EOF

fatal: index-pack failed

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

no more a problem because the TypeScript repository has been moved to 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript